# File metadata is not getting updated in Firestore Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have created a Cloud Function that trigger on any new file upload in Firebase Storage. Once successful upload function will update its metadata, but even though setting new metadata with 'setMetadata()' is not getting applied. There is no error during the process and but on checking for updated metadata, the new one is not reflecting.

```
exports.onImageUpload = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {  
  const storageRef = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);

  var metadata = {
      'uploader': 'unknown'   
  }

  await storageRef.file(object.name).setMetadata(metadata).then(function(data) {
    console.log('Success');
    console.log(data);
    return;
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    return ;
  });
  return;
});
```

There is no error, and on Cloud Function log its printing 'Success' message. Also "metageneration: '2'" property also got updated, which means it should have updated metadata with new values, but it didn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that if you want to set **custom key/value pairs** they must be in the `metadata` key of the object you pass to the `setMetadata()` method, i.e. the `metadata` object in your case. This is explained in the [API Reference Documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#setMetadata) for node.js.

So the following will work:

```
exports.onImageUpload = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const storageRef = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);

    var metadata = {
        metadata: {
            'uploader': 'unknown'
        }
    }

    try {
        const setFileMetadataResponse = await storageRef.file(object.name).setMetadata(metadata);
        console.log('Success');
        console.log(setFileMetadataResponse[0]);
        return null;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked thanks a lot, though later I realised that I have tried similar way to update 'metadata' property, but instead of using 'metadata' keyword as object name I used 'customMetadata', so that actually messed up my day :P.

Comment: .updateMetadata for the web w / customMetadata as key for custom object https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata